# Connect to sql server via transitional computer issue, login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, connection, powershell-remoting

I have SQL Server 2008 to which I can connect using domain user credentials. There are many computers in the network and if I login under that domain user I can successfully connect to SQL Server (using Windows Authentication).

The problem is when I use PowerShell remoting and establish remote session from computer A to computer B. When I run our `dbtool` that tries to connect to SqlServer (in remote session) "`login failed for NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`" error occurs.

It's strange, because I establish remote session under same domain user. Why `ANONYMOUS` is being passesd to SqlServer?

Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe a kerberos double hop issue?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is Delegation issue. I have a similar issue with PowerShell remoting and accessing file shares on another computer. I  get rather descriptive error message: "The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And once again I'm answering my own question due to lack of other answers.

Computers communication chain: `A -> B -> C`.

So the problem is indeed with Kerberos authorization delegation feature (more there: http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/WhatIsDelegation.html). When I establish remote session from computer `A` to computer `B`, computer `B` sends to computer `C` `null session` (because delegation is disalloved). Thats why SQL Server on computer `C` sees me as `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`.

My current workaround is to talk to SQL Server from computer `A` (copy necessary utilities there), because I have no way to enable delegation. For this scenarion computer `A` sends correct authorization token to computer `C`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried enabling CredSSP (not supported on W2k3 though)?

```
## Client
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer "*.domain.com"

## Server
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

Comment: that worked for me. Remember to include the -Authentication CredSSP parameter when using invoke-command after setting CSSP set up.